# HTTPHandler write Binary Data to Response , load image 

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, user-controls, httphandler

iv'e got a repeater bonded to a list of entities

```
    BL_Engine engine = (BL_Engine)Application["engine"];
    List<AppProduct> products = engine.Get_Products();
    Repeater1.DataSource = products;
    Repeater1.DataBind();
```

iv'e also got a user control i use to represent these product entities , i do this by overriding the Databind() in the user control :

```
    public override void DataBind()
    {
        AppProduct product = (Page.GetDataItem() as AppProduct);
        lbl_title.Text = product.Title;
        lbl_short.Text = product.Short;
        lbl_date.Text = product.Date.ToShortDateString();                       
        Session["current_img"] = product.Image1;            
        base.DataBind();
    }
```

in my HttpHanlder object kept in a .ashx file  i write the image to the response 
the response happens only once so only the last picture is written to (ALL) the user controls.

```
     public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
     {
        byte [] image = (byte[])context.Session["current_img"];                  
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/bmp";
        context.Response.OutputStream.Write(image, 0, image.Length);
     }
```

any idea how i could write the binary data for each individual control

thanks in advance
eran.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest a different approach.

Declare a regular html image element in your control and set the "runat=server" property as  so:

```
<img src="" runat="server" id="img_product" />
```

Then change your `DataBind()` method to do this instead:

```
 public override void DataBind()
 {
       AppProduct product = (Page.GetDataItem() as AppProduct);
       lbl_title.Text = product.Title;
       lbl_short.Text = product.Short;
       lbl_date.Text = product.Date.ToShortDateString();                       
       img_product.src= "\"data:image/jpg;base64,"+System.Convert.ToBase64String(product.Image1)+"\"";
        base.DataBind();
 }
```

And get rid of the HTTPHandler. You don't need it for this.

Comment: i actually tried something of the sort when i save the encoded bytes 
to a file with the correct extension and added it as it's src attribute 
thanks , ill give it another go

Comment: that doesn't seem to work ...
where did you get that conversion string from . i don't recognize the syntax

Comment: @eranotzer It works quite well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524.aspx `Convert.ToBase64String` takes a `byte[]`  and returns a Base64-encoded string. Check my link to MSDN documentation. I've used it, that's why I referenced it.

Comment: yeah i realize this could work , i'm trying to get to the root of the problem since my images ain't showing , ill have a look at your link.
thanks.
please review my edit .

Comment: i took a look at the in msdn , still id like to know where you took the syntax "\data:image/jpg;base64,"......
so i could check if there's something wrong with that syntax since it does not show the images , i know the base64bitstring represents it fine , but maybe the attachments wrong ..

Comment: @eranotzer Ahhh, that syntax... See Wikipedia, for example: (scroll down to the Examples): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme or here: http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/

Comment: @eranotzer you found it too. Are your images jpeg, png, gif? In your code you set the content type as image/bmp. Is that accurate? Why bmp? That's odd.

Comment: i didn't think much of it i took it from an example i saw ..
but your right , ill need to some how save the images type as well 
because users would be able to load all sorts of images.
thanks for the walkthrew

Answer (score 1):

Change your handler so that it takes the id of the current product as a query string parameter. In the handler load the correct image data based on the parameter and write that instead.

Comment: i thought of that ,
but then i would have to go to my data base for each image
when i already got all the info and images out 
that would really slow down performance  ...

Comment: The solution to that is to not return the image data with the product, either by excluding it from the object or lazy loading it. This approach had the benefit of allowing you to return 304's for the images so they are not downloaded every time.

Comment: i don't really know what 304's are .
maybe you could refer me to a good source to see how to use them ?

Comment: look at my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410357/asp-net-ashx-handler-not-caching/7410374#7410374. Basically you check to see if the file has changed since it was last downloaded by the browser and if not you tell it not to download the file

Answer (score 0):

well to conclude , for this case i think  the best practice would be @icarus's answer ,
not the disregard @kmcc049's answer i just hadn't dug into it since it seemed like a more complicated architecture for my app.

**in this case DROP THE HTTPHANDLER .**

i saved the image's type , and data from the post file.

```
        public enum ImageType : byte {jpg,jpeg,png,gif}  

        private byte[] Get_Image(HttpPostedFile file)
        {
            ImageType type = GetType(file.ContentType); 
            if (file.InputStream.Length <= 1)
                return null;
            byte[] imageData = new byte[file.InputStream.Length + 1 + 1];
            file.InputStream.Read(imageData, 1, imageData.Length+1);
            imageData[0] =(byte)type;
            return imageData;
         }

         private ImageType GetType(string _type)
         {
            ImageType t = default(ImageType); 
            string s = _type.Substring(_type.IndexOf('/')+1).ToLower() ;
            switch (s)
            {
                 case "jpg": t = ImageType.jpg;
                      break;
                 case "jpeg": t = ImageType.jpeg;
                      break;
                 case "png": t = ImageType.png;
                      break;
                 case "gif": t = ImageType.gif;
                      break;
            }
            return t; 
       }
```

then i extracted and added it to the user control in my DataBind override(in my user control) :

```
       public override void DataBind()
       {
            AppProduct product = (Page.GetDataItem() as AppProduct);
            img_main.Attributes.Add("src",Build_Img_Data(product.Image1));                        
            base.DataBind();
       }


       private string Build_Img_Data(byte[] imageData)
       {
           ImageType type = (ImageType)imageData[0] ;
           byte[] new_imageData = new byte[imageData.Length - 1];
           Array.ConstrainedCopy(imageData, 1, new_imageData, 0, new_imageData.Length); 
           MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(new_imageData);
           string base64String = string.Format("data:image/{0};base64,{1}",type.ToString(),Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray()));
           return base64String;
       }
```